# Multiple Web Projects in one solution, Config Transforms

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config, configuration-management

I am attempting to setup Config Transforms on my project that I migrated to VS 2010. The web project works just fine, but I have a WCF Host project that I seem to be unable to add transforms.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Semi-related ... check out the SlowCheetah VS add-in at ... [visualstudiogallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the transformations, just be sure that the actual web.config file is setup properly for your debugging process as the transforms are ONLY completed when you publish the project to a different location!

Comment: I figured it out, sorry for the delay. I converted the WCF host project from a class library to a WCF project. Then I had the ability.